# Prime or not Prime output slow

Tags: c, integer, primes, slowdown

This is C program. This is my `code` in the below. I used `nano` in terminal. When I compile and test with `./a.out 9872349901` but it's took me exact one minute to get a result... Does anybody know why is it slow? (I believe it probably is too long number but I used `int isprime(long long n) {`This is for my CS course class when I do labcheck, it is automated assignment grade to get points but it won't show up mine because labcheck wouldn't wait for it.

```
/**
 * Make a function called isprime that returns true (i.e. 1) if the integer
 * number passed to it is prime and false (i.e. 0) if it is composite (i.e.
 * not prime.)  A number is composite if it is divisible by 2 or any odd number
 * up to the square root of the number itself, otherwise it is prime.
 * Hint: n is divisible by m if (n % m == 0)
 */

/**
 * Using the isprime function you made above, test if a number provided on the
 * command line is prime or not. The program should print a usage message if no
 * number is provided ("Usage: p4 <number>\n") and print a warning if the number
 * is less than 2 ("input number should be > 1\n") and should be able to handle
 * numbers greater than 4 billion.
 * 
 * Example input/output:
 * ./p4 9872349901
 * 9872349901 is prime
 * ./p4 65
 * 65 is not prime
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

int isprime(long long n) {
    for (long long i = 2; i != n; ++i)
        if (n%i == 0)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf ("Usage: p4 <number>\n");
        return -1;
    }
    char* p;
    long long n = strtoll(argv[1], &p, 10);
    if (n < 2 || *p != '\0')
    {
        printf ("input wrong\n");
        return -1;
    }
    int result = isprime(n);

    if (result == 1)
        printf ("%lld is prime\n", n);
    else
        printf ("%lld is not prime\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Many different numbers works perfectly but not for 9872349901 because that's the number what the instructor would test my assignment.

Here is my preview when I do "lab check"

```
cs25681@cs:/instructor/class/cs25681/cs/h5> labcheck 5
Checking assignment #5:
p1:
p2:
p3:
p4:
-3.0 output of program (p4) is not correct for input '9872349901':
------ Yours: ------
---- Reference: ----
9872349901 is prime
--------------------
p5:
p6:
p7:
p8:
```

I wanted to test it for each different number so here is preview with `./a.out <number>`

```
cs25681@cs:/lecture/class/cs25681/cs> ./a.out 3
3 is prime
cs25681@cs:/lecture/class/cs25681/cs> ./a.out 1
input wrong
cs25681@cs:/lecture/class/cs25681/cs> ./a.out 9
9 is not prime
cs25681@cs:/lecture/class/cs25681/cs> ./a.out 9872349901
9872349901 is prime
cs25681@cs:/lecture/class/cs25681/cs> echo "took 43 seconds to output"
took 43 seconds to output
cs25681@cs:/lecture/class/cs25681/cs>
```

Comment: You don't need to check `[2..n]`, `[2..sqrt(n)]` is enough. You should check wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Computational_methods

Comment: It even says in your instructions in the header comment, that you are supposed to test only up to sqrt(n).

Comment: Where do I put sqrt(n)? I don't think I have done with sqrt(n) before in any c program.

Comment: Use `for (long long i = 2; i * i <= n; ++i)`.  A better algorithm would test 2, then test 3, 5, 7, ...; better still, test 2 and 3, then 6*N±1 for N = 1, 2, 3, … which tests 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25 (which is the first time it isn't picking a prime pair), etc.  Note that you don't use `sqrt(N)`; you use `i * i <= N`.  Or, if you must use `sqrt(N)`, you calculate the value before the loop and use the calculated value.  Round up to the next integer.

Comment: Enough theory, in practice, it's slow because checking whether finding a prime in general IS slow. The only way to make it reasonably fast for numbers that take over a minute, is to parallelize (you can either buy a special CPU that was designed with parallel algorithms in mind or just use something like OpenGL and perform some voodoo shader magic on your GPU using frame buffers (1 pixel = is X divisible by Y (how you get those is another problem) and write either white or black or something in fragment shader), or if you have a good GPU, Compute shaders could be used for that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring a comment of mine into an answer.*</sup>

Use:

```
for (long long i = 2; i * i <= n; ++i)
```

This limits the testing until `i` is just greater than the square root of `n`, as suggested in the notes in your code.

A better algorithm would test 2, then test odd numbers 3, 5, 7, …, which reduces the amount of testing by a lot.

Better still, test 2 and 3, then 6*N±1 for N = 1, 2, 3, … which tests 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25 (which is the first time it isn't picking a prime pair), etc.

```
if (n <= 1)
    return 0;
if (n == 2 || n == 3)
    return 1;
if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0)
    return 0;
for (unsigned long long x = 5; x * x <= n; x += 6)
{
    if (n % x == 0 || n % (x + 2) == 0)
        return 0;
}
return 1;
```

Note that you don't use `sqrt(N)`; you use `i * i <= N`. Or, if you must use `sqrt(N)`, you calculate the value before the loop and use the calculated value, rounded up to the next integer (`ceil()` from `<math.h>`).  At least, that was what my benchmarking a few years ago told me.

JFTR: transferring the code above into the code in the question, and timing `p4 9872349901` yields the report that it is prime in an elapsed time of about 0.005 seconds (on an ordinary 2016 15" MacBook Pro with 2.7 GHz Intel Core i7 processor).  I also tried 98723499017333 (adding 4 digits to the right end of the number, and getting a number of non-prime values before hitting on this one) which is reported as a prime in 0.044 seconds.  The non-prime reports were quicker, of course.

Comment: Some of this code is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as file `isprime.c` in the [Primes](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/Primes) sub-directory.